# Symmetry group of QCD

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, phase-transition, quantum-chromodynamics, research-level

In "Remarks on the chiral phase transition in chromodynamics" (1984) by Pisarski and Wilczek it is stated that the (classical) global flavor symmetry is $SU(2)\times SU(2) \times U_A(1)$ where the $U_A(1)$ is broken by an anomaly. This seems wrong. Where is the unbroken $U_V(1)$? Is there an explanation? This seems essential for the point of the whole paper? Am I missing something?

Comment: Baryon/quark number.

Comment: @CosmasZachos, could you expand? Are you saying it is there but Wilczek is not considering it part of the flavor symmetry. It seems essential whether it is there or not. Equation (2) for example gives the transformation rule if $U_A(1)$ is restored. But if there is also the vector symmetry this is even the transformation rule if $U_A(1)$ is not restored. So this would mean that all the conclusion for a restored axial symmetry would actually hold when it is not restored. (And to get the results for a restored axial symmetry he needs to consider an extra U(1) which he did not do at all.)

Comment: Quark number is assumed and inviolable, so it effectively drops off the problem, and is not part of the flavor symmetry: it does not scramble flavors; it does not "see" flavors. For one flavor, it *is* the flavor symmetry, as they say. I don't understand your point. Have you articulated it unambiguously in your question?

Comment: I think I understand your point. If the symmetry breaking is $SU(2)\times SU(2) \times U_A(1)  \times U_V(1) \to G \times U_V(1)$ then the $U_V(1)$ symmetry is just along for the ride and is not important. The order parameter can just be taken to be a singlet of the $U_V(1)$. (The $SU(N_c)$ symmetry is not considered for the same reason.)

Comment: So an important difference with $U_A(1)$ is that Wilczek does assume that (if restored) it will be broken spontaneously (in addition to it having been approximate anyway because it was explicitly broken by the anomaly).

I am not sure about the motivation for this assumption though. I would think we can just as well make the simpler assumption that only the "chiral" $SU(N_f)\times SU(N_f)$ breaks down to $SU(N_f)$. Why if the $U_A(1)$ is present does it have to break. (Of course this is going past the scope of the original question. So I should really open a new one.)